# Read drive information of virtual machine with c#

Tags: c#, monitoring, vmware

I'm still working on a small programm where I'm trying to monitor various computer data like temperature, clock speeds... (CPU, GPU, Drives, RAM). The data is mainly received over the WMI interface of OpenHardwareMonitor, this works fine. But OHM doesn't provide any useful Drive data, so I'm currently reading it from the windows WMI interface. (Win32_DiskDrive)

Everything workes fine if you work on a physical machine. But when I try it in an Virtual Machine, I don't receive any drive data at all.

Have you any idea what I should do in order to get important drive data on a virtual machine? I need the space used and the total drive space of the virtual drive. Furthermore it would be nice if I'm able to get the temperature and the SMART Status of the physical drives of the computer.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `System.IO` functionalities?

Take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-get-information-about-files-folders-and-drives), might be what you need!

This allow you doing things like (from link):

```
    // You can also use System.Environment.GetLogicalDrives to
    // obtain names of all logical drives on the computer.
    System.IO.DriveInfo di = new System.IO.DriveInfo(@"C:\");
    Console.WriteLine(di.TotalFreeSpace);
    Console.WriteLine(di.VolumeLabel);

    // Get the root directory and print out some information about it.
    System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirInfo = di.RootDirectory;
    Console.WriteLine(dirInfo.Attributes.ToString());
```

Also, code showing what you actually use/what isn't working would have been nice to have in your question.